# Is \def sensitive to spacing?

Tags: macros, tex-core

In the code below, it took me a long time to figure out that the space in the second line below beginning with `\def` generates an error.

I'm new here.  Where is the documentation of `\def` that would help me understand this issue?

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer} 

\begin{document} 
\def\funa(#1,#2){ (#2)*(#1)^2} %  OK
%\def\funa(#1,#2) { (#2)*(#1)^2 }  % NOT OK ...WHY?

\begin{frame} 
      \pgfmathparse {\funa(3,4)}  \pgfmathresult \\   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with either beamer or spacing (that is, *printed* spaces) so I changed your tags, if that's okay.

Comment: Though not as detailed and thorough as @RyanReich's answer, if you're just looking for basic documentation, Wikibooks is often a good place to start (in addition to TeX.SX). Here's the general [TeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX), the [LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX), and [the entry for `\def`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/def).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 28):

When writing a `\def`inition, you have to understand that, with one minor exception, *every* character counts (see *TeX By Topic*, starting at p. 112, "Delimited parameters").  Namely, if you write

```
\def\macro<some text pattern involving #1, #2, ...>{...}
```

then TeX will search for the exact appearance of the pattern you give.  Thus, if you write

```
\def\funa(#1,#2) { (#2)*(#1)^2 }
```

then in use, TeX will expect to see `\funa` followed by a `(`, something without `,` that it takes to be `#1`, then some more stuff without `)` that it takes to be `#2`, then a `)`, and finally *a space*, because you wrote a space there.  So if you use it without the space you will get an error.

The minor exception is that spaces *immediately* following the macro name are ignored: `\def\macro{...}` and `\def\macro {...}` are the same.  This is a side-effect of how TeX converts your input into its internal directives, namely, that all spaces following a control word are ignored during tokenization.  This elision occurs *before* the definition is even begun, and is not a property of `\def` at all but of general TeX syntax.  However, for you, the space is protected from `\funa` by the intervening text, and is thus interpreted according to the macro definition syntax.